# Multiple wildcards in Azure RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

I saw this in the documentation:

*You can also have multiple wildcards in a string. For example, the following string represents all query permissions for Cost Management.*

```
Microsoft.CostManagement/*/query/*
```

What does the first wildcard mean before the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It represents the resources under the `Microsoft.CostManagement` resource provider, e.g. `externalBillingAccounts`, `externalSubscriptions`.

With the action permission `Microsoft.CostManagement/*/query/*`, you will be able to query usage data under `Microsoft.CostManagement`, you can understand you have the sum of permissions `Microsoft.CostManagement/externalBillingAccounts/query/*` and `Microsoft.CostManagement/externalSubscriptions/query/*`, etc.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftcostmanagement